# Netbeans doesn't recognize project folder

Tags: windows, netbeans-7, xubuntu

I have several projects made in Netbeans 7.2 installed on Windows XP SP3. Last week I have installed Xubuntu 12.10 in the same machine (in a different partition), and on Xubuntu I also installed Netbeans 7.2. So far nothing went wrong and everything is running smoothly.

Now the problem I'm facing with is that not all the projects I've done in Netbeans on Windows are recognized by Netbeans on Xubuntu, it just doesn't recognize the project folder. Why is this happening, why are some of the projects recognized and others aren't recognized?

Another issue I'm dealing with is that when I click on 'Open Project' in Netbeans on Xubuntu, under the 'Look in' options none of my USB thumb drives appear, but I'm able to work with them  in any other application of Xubuntu.

I would much appreciate any help that could cast a light on this two issues I'm dealling with.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please fix the title of your question please.

Comment: The title of the question issue is fixed.

Comment: The second part of my question I've already solved it, just navigating all way the up to Root, e.g. '/', then '/media' and in that folder it's my thumb drive. But still I haven't manage to get a solution to my main problem, why Netbeans doesn't recognize the project folder?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I finally solve it, by starting a new project in Xubuntu Netbeans. I kept everything the same, not only classes but also the Substance LAF library and it's working perfectly.

The only difference is the in name of the project folder, originally was 'Calculador Validade Concessões' and now I've changed it to 'Calculador Validade Concessoes'. I think it it was caused caused by the 'õ' character in project folder name, since java code files are Unicode.